# Removing LaTeX Warning: Label ... multiply defined using **knitr**

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have a document where I define a figure label once inside `fig.caption` option in a chunk, and then reference it in the text using `\ref{}`. For instance,

````
```{r dataCorrA, results="hold", echo = FALSE, fig.pos = "ht", fig.width=5, fig.height=5, fig.cap="\\label{fig:dataCorr} Some caption."}

data("airquality", package = "datasets")
GGally::ggcorr(airquality)
````

blah blah blah ... figure \ref{fig:dataCorr}

But upon knitting, I get

> LaTeX Warning: Label `fig:dataCorr' multiply defined.

How can I get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This label is incorrect. Labels are defined with two colons `::`. 
Eg. In **knitr**, the label option must have two colons, not one. Change the `\\label`and the `\ref` in text that follows.

````
```{r dataCorrA, results="hold", echo = FALSE, fig.pos = "ht", fig.width=5, fig.height=5, fig.cap="\\label{fig::dataCorr} Some caption."}

data("airquality", package = "datasets")
GGally::ggcorr(airquality)
````

blah blah blah ... figure \ref{fig::dataCorr}